# Как запустить IDEA через терминал в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Не могу запустить IDEA через терминал. Пишет такую ошибку:

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin$ ispect.sh
ispect.sh: command not found
aleksey@aleksey:~/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin$ cd ~
aleksey@aleksey:~$ ~/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin/inspect.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option    MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger    (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig  for more info.
invalid args:[inspect]
Expected parameters: <project_file_path> <inspection_profile>  <output_path> <inspections_profile> -- use here profile name configured in     the project or locally or path to the inspection profile; can be stabbed     when one of the -e|-profileName|-profilePath is used
[<options>]
 Available options are:
 -d <directory_path>  --  directory to be inspected. Optional. Whole     project is inspected by default.
-e                   --  skip  
-v[0|1|2]            --  verbose level. 0 - silent, 1 - verbose, 2 - most   verbose. 
-profileName         --  name of a profile defined in project 
-profilePath         --  absolute path to the profile file
aleksey@aleksey:~$
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска IntelliJ IDEA надо запускать `idea.sh`. Из папки `~/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin`:

```
./idea.sh
```

После первого запуска будет создана ссылка для запуска из меню.

Comment: одной командой — `~/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin/idea.sh` — быстрее будет.

Answer (score -1):

Через sudo ./bin/idea.sh
В дальше возможны различные проблемы (типа Too many restarts of GPU-process (JCEF)) из за прав доступа.
Решается создание ярлыка (что не всегда происходит автоматически) меню Tool/Create Desktop Entry.
Ну и не забываем добавить память меню Help/Change Memory Settings

Comment: минус за абсолютно бессмысленное и вредное использование учётной записи суперпользователя для выполнения не-административных задач.